# Return a single key from a Hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, key

I would like to know how to return a specific key from a Hash?

Example:

```
moves = Hash["Kick", 100, "Punch", 50]
```

How would I return the first key "Kick" from this Hash?

NOTE: I'm aware that the following function will return all keys from the hash but I'm just interested in returning one key.

```
moves.keys #=> ["Kick", "Punch"]
```

Comment: Why are you only interested in returning one key?

Comment: I'm designing a game and using the hash keys in print statements. Therefore, I needed to access one key at a time.

Comment: A "print statement" as in displaying the information to the user, or to the programmer?

Comment: It would be a 'puts' or 'p' statement. I'm displaying the keys to the users or players in the game. That's the way it's designed, at least for now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
    moves.keys[0]
```

will give you the first key. 
You can get all keys by changing the argument passed (0, 1,...etc)

Answer (score 21):

You can use:

```
first_key, first_value = moves.first
```

Or equivalently:

```
first_key = moves.first.first
```

Quite nice too:

```
first_key = moves.each_key.first
```

The other possibility, `moves.keys.first` will build an intermediary array for all keys which could potentially be very big.

Note that Ruby 1.8 makes no guarantee on the order of a hash, so the key you will get not always be the same. In Ruby 1.9, you will always get the same key (`"Kick"` in your example).

Comment: Or `moves.first[0]` if `.first.first` looks too much like stuttering. Hope you don't mind me wrecking your lucky "all sevens" rep.

Answer (score 8):

`moves.keys.first` will accomplish that.

Comment: May work in Ruby 1.9, where the hash order is preserved, but not in 1.8 (the "first" key will be any one of the possible keys)

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. Thanks!

Comment: @Zabba I've moved up in version long ago, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Zabba Doesn't this question presuppose that it's Ruby 1.9? Otherwise, the question would not seem to make sense.

Comment: Yea, I'm in 1.9 too. Thanks @Zabba for making the distinction

Comment: @sawa, not really. It could have been that the OP was on 1.8 and was unaware of this difference in Hash between 1.8 and 1.9 - so I added a comment to indicate the difference.